# Wicket - Tree + jquery-treeview

Tags: java, jquery, treeview, tree, wicket

I'm a newb in wicket and jquery, i'd like a simple tree in my wicket page, linked to jquery-treeview. ("simple", i mean one root, some children having may be some children, ...).

Every node contains a label with its name and some links or buttons.

Everything i found looks really hard....
I like the example 'RecursivePanel' but i can't make it work with jquery-treeview.

What do you think of the solution below. I don't like a lot the fact that is splitted in two components but i didn't find any good solution.

So the tree is composed of 2 components.

- The NodePanel, containing the name of the node and a NodeChildrenPanel into a <li>.
- The NodeChildrenPanel, containing a label if it is a leaf or a NodePanel again for each child.

NodePanel.html

```
<wicket:panel>
  <li>
    <span wicket:id="name"></span>
    <span wicket:id="children"></span>
  </li>
</wicket:panel>
```

NodePanel.java

```
class NodePanel extends Panel {
    Node(String id, Node node) {
        super(id);

        setRenderBodyOnly(true);

        add(new Label("name", node.getName()));
        add(new NodeChildrenPanel("children", node));
    }
}
```

NodeChildrenPanel.html

```
<wicket:panel>
  <ul>
    <li wicket:id="children"></li>
  </ul>
</wicket:panel>
```

NodeChildrenPanel.java

```
class NodeChildrenPanel extends Panel {
    public NodeChildrenPanel(String id, Node node) {
        super(id);

        setRenderBodyOnly(true);

        if (node.isLeaf()){
            Label l = new Label("children");
            l.setVisible(false);
            add(l);
        } else {
            RepeatingView rv = new RepeatingView("children");

            for (Node child : node.getChildren()){
                if (child.isLeaf()){
                        rv.add(new Label(rv.newChildId(), child.getName()));
                } else {
                        rv.add(new NodePanel(rv.newChildId(), child));
                }
            }

            add(rv);
        }       
 }
```

}

In the page,

The root node is created into a <ul>

```
 <ul id="my_tree_ul">
    <div wicket:id="my_tree"></div>
 </ul>
```

---

```
add(new NodePanel("my_tree", getSession().getMyRootNode());
```

And the <ul> is linked to jquery-treeview.

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    String js = "$(document).ready(function(){ $(\"#my_tree_ul\")
                     .treeview({animated: \"fast\",       
                          });
                 });");

    response.renderJavaScript(js, null);
}
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: You can try to create single component and use wicket:fragment (http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/usingfragments.html) for node.

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Treegrid package](http://wicketstuff.org/grid-examples/tree-grid/simple?3) provided by [Wicketstuff extensions](http://wicketstuff.org/)